# Dropdown menu, cannot get SlideDown() to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I hate posting questions on here as I like to figure out a solution for myself however I just cannot figure this one out.

I have a navigation menu that is spat out by wordpress which is 3 deep. I am trying to make a big dropdown and I have it functioning fine with just css but now I am looking to animate it and am just having problems.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yRNQt/

and here is the code:

```
    <div id="mid-nav">
  <ul id="midnav">
    <ul id="topmenu-{topmenu slug}[-{increment}]" class="topmenu">
      <li id="nav-menu-item-62" class="main-menu-item  menu-item-depth-0 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-5 current_page_item"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/" class="menu-link main-menu-link">Home</a></li>
      <li id="nav-menu-item-68" class="main-menu-item  menu-item-depth-0 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/why-renewal/" class="menu-link main-menu-link">Why Renewal</a>
        <ul  id="testtt" class="sub-menu menu-odd  menu-depth-1">
        <div id="special"><img src="images/Untitled-3.png" /></div>
        <div id="contact"> <img src="images/Untitled-4.png" /></div>
          <li id="nav-menu-item-69" class="sub-menu-item  menu-item-depth-1 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/why-renewal/fibrex/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Fibrex</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu menu-even sub-sub-menu menu-depth-2">
              <li id="nav-menu-item-70" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/why-renewal/fibrex/history-of-firex/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">History of firex</a></li>
              <li id="nav-menu-item-71" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/why-renewal/fibrex/what-is-fibrex/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">What is fibrex</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li id="nav-menu-item-72" class="sub-menu-item  menu-item-depth-1 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/why-renewal/green-seal-cert/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Green Seal Cert</a></li>
          <li id="nav-menu-item-75" class="sub-menu-item  menu-item-depth-1 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/why-renewal/renewal-warranty/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Renewal Warranty</a></li>
          <li id="nav-menu-item-76" class="sub-menu-item  menu-item-depth-1 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/why-renewal/what-to-look-for/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">What to look for</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="nav-menu-item-63" class="main-menu-item  menu-item-depth-0 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/about/" class="menu-link main-menu-link">About</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu menu-odd  menu-depth-1">
        <div id="special"><img src="images/Untitled-3.png" /></div>
        <div id="contact"> <img src="images/Untitled-4.png" /></div>
          <li id="nav-menu-item-148" class="sub-menu-item  menu-item-depth-1 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/about/our-pledge/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Our Pledge</a></li>
          <li id="nav-menu-item-149" class="sub-menu-item  menu-item-depth-1 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/about/testimonials/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Testimonials</a></li>
          <li id="nav-menu-item-146" class="sub-menu-item  menu-item-depth-1 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/about/articles/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Articles</a></li>
          <li id="nav-menu-item-147" class="sub-menu-item  menu-item-depth-1 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/about/contact-us/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Contact us</a></li>
          <li id="nav-menu-item-145" class="sub-menu-item  menu-item-depth-1 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/about/appointment-calendar/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Appointment Calendar</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="nav-menu-item-150" class="main-menu-item  menu-item-depth-0 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/windows/" class="menu-link main-menu-link">Windows</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu menu-odd  menu-depth-1">
        <div id="special"><img src="images/Untitled-3.png" /></div>
        <div id="contact"> <img src="images/Untitled-4.png" /></div>
          <li id="nav-menu-item-151" class="sub-menu-item  menu-item-depth-1 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/windows/double-hung/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Double Hung</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu menu-even sub-sub-menu menu-depth-2">
              <li id="nav-menu-item-152" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/windows/double-hung/colors/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Colors</a></li>
              <li id="nav-menu-item-153" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/windows/double-hung/glass/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Glass</a></li>
              <li id="nav-menu-item-154" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/windows/double-hung/grilles/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Grilles</a></li>
              <li id="nav-menu-item-155" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/windows/double-hung/hardware/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Hardware</a></li>
              <li id="nav-menu-item-156" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/windows/double-hung/screens/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Screens</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li id="nav-menu-item-157" class="sub-menu-item  menu-item-depth-1 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/windows/gliding/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Gliding</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu menu-even sub-sub-menu menu-depth-2">
              <li id="nav-menu-item-158" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/windows/gliding/colors/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Colors</a></li>
              <li id="nav-menu-item-159" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/windows/gliding/glass/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Glass</a></li>
              <li id="nav-menu-item-160" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/windows/gliding/grilles/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Grilles</a></li>
              <li id="nav-menu-item-161" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/windows/gliding/hardware/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Hardware</a></li>
              <li id="nav-menu-item-162" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/windows/gliding/screens/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Screens</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li id="nav-menu-item-163" class="sub-menu-item  menu-item-depth-1 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/windows/casement/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Casement</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu menu-even sub-sub-menu menu-depth-2">
              <li id="nav-menu-item-164" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/windows/casement/colors/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Colors</a></li>
              <li id="nav-menu-item-165" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/windows/casement/glass/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Glass</a></li>
              <li id="nav-menu-item-166" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/windows/casement/grilles/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Grilles</a></li>
              <li id="nav-menu-item-167" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/windows/casement/hardware/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Hardware</a></li>
              <li id="nav-menu-item-168" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/windows/casement/screens/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Screens</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li id="nav-menu-item-169" class="sub-menu-item  menu-item-depth-1 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/windows/awning/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Awning</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu menu-even sub-sub-menu menu-depth-2">
              <li id="nav-menu-item-170" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/windows/awning/colors/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Colors</a></li>
              <li id="nav-menu-item-171" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/windows/awning/glass/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Glass</a></li>
              <li id="nav-menu-item-172" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/windows/awning/grilles/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Grilles</a></li>
              <li id="nav-menu-item-173" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/windows/awning/hardware/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Hardware</a></li>
              <li id="nav-menu-item-174" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/windows/awning/screens/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Screens</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li id="nav-menu-item-175" class="sub-menu-item  menu-item-depth-1 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/windows/baybow/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Bay/bow</a></li>
          <li id="nav-menu-item-176" class="sub-menu-item  menu-item-depth-1 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/windows/specialty/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Specialty</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="nav-menu-item-66" class="main-menu-item  menu-item-depth-0 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/doors/" class="menu-link main-menu-link">Doors</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu menu-odd  menu-depth-1">
        <div id="special"><img src="images/Untitled-3.png" /></div>
        <div id="contact"> <img src="images/Untitled-4.png" /></div>
          <li id="nav-menu-item-177" class="sub-menu-item  menu-item-depth-1 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/doors/narroline-gliding/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Narroline gliding</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu menu-even sub-sub-menu menu-depth-2">
              <li id="nav-menu-item-178" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/doors/narroline-gliding/colors/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Colors</a></li>
              <li id="nav-menu-item-179" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/doors/narroline-gliding/grilles/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Grilles</a></li>
              <li id="nav-menu-item-180" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/doors/narroline-gliding/hardware/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Hardware</a></li>
              <li id="nav-menu-item-181" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/doors/narroline-gliding/screens/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Screens</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li id="nav-menu-item-188" class="sub-menu-item  menu-item-depth-1 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/doors/frenchwood-hinged/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Frenchwood hinged</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu menu-even sub-sub-menu menu-depth-2">
              <li id="nav-menu-item-196" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/doors/frenchwood-hinged/colors/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Colors</a></li>
              <li id="nav-menu-item-195" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/doors/frenchwood-hinged/grilles/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Grilles</a></li>
              <li id="nav-menu-item-194" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/doors/frenchwood-hinged/hardware/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Hardware</a></li>
              <li id="nav-menu-item-193" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/doors/frenchwood-hinged/screens/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Screens</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li id="nav-menu-item-187" class="sub-menu-item  menu-item-depth-1 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/doors/frenchwood-gliding/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Frenchwood gliding</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu menu-even sub-sub-menu menu-depth-2">
              <li id="nav-menu-item-192" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/doors/frenchwood-gliding/colors/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Colors</a></li>
              <li id="nav-menu-item-191" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/doors/frenchwood-gliding/grilles/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Grilles</a></li>
              <li id="nav-menu-item-190" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/doors/frenchwood-gliding/hardware/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Hardware</a></li>
              <li id="nav-menu-item-189" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/doors/frenchwood-gliding/screens/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Screens</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li id="nav-menu-item-186" class="sub-menu-item  menu-item-depth-1 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/doors/perma-shield-gliding/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Perma Shield Gliding</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu menu-even sub-sub-menu menu-depth-2">
              <li id="nav-menu-item-183" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/doors/perma-shield-gliding/colors/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Colors</a></li>
              <li id="nav-menu-item-182" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/doors/perma-shield-gliding/grilles/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Grilles</a></li>
              <li id="nav-menu-item-185" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/doors/perma-shield-gliding/hardware/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Hardware</a></li>
              <li id="nav-menu-item-184" class="sub-menu-item sub-sub-menu-item menu-item-depth-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.renewmywindows.com/doors/perma-shield-gliding/screens/" class="menu-link sub-menu-link">Screens</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 @charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

/*depth 0*/

#mid-nav ul {
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    /* cancels gap caused by top padding in Opera 7.54 */
    margin-left: 0;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000;
    line-height: 18px;/* fixes Firefox 0.9.3 */
}
#mid-nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    /* matches link padding except for left and right */
    padding-top: 5px;
}
#mid-nav ul li a {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000;
    border: none;
}

#mid-nav li:hover a {/*this keeps top menu items colors whilst down in the lower ul */
    background-color: #cfcfcf;
    /*color: white;*/
}
#mid-nav .active {
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}
/*depth 1*/

#special {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 220px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;/*padding-top:-40px;*/
}
#contact {
    padding-top: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 220px;
    float: right;
    margin: 10px;/*padding-top:-40px!important; */
}
#mid-nav ul li ul {
    display: none;
}
#mid-nav ul li ul li {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    width: 200px;
    margin-right:100px;

}
#mid-nav ul li ul a{
    width:1400px;
    background-color:transparent!important;
    /*#mid-nav ul li ul a {*/
    color:#000;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-align: left!important;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;

    border: none;
}   
#mid-nav ul li:hover > ul {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 40px;
    width: 800px;
    height: 250px;
    /*background-color: #cfcfcf;*/
    display: inline;
    text-align: left;
}
#mid-nav li li:hover a {/*this keeps level 1 menu items colors whilst down in the lower ul */
    background-color: #cfcfcf!important;
}
#mid-nav ul li ul li:hover {
    background-color: #cfcfcf!important;
}

/*depth 2*/

#mid-nav ul li ul li ul{

}
#mid-nav ul li ul li:hover > ul {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 175px;
    right: 0;
    top: 0px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 245px;
    background-color: #cfcfcf;/*!important;*/
    display: inline;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
#mid-nav ul li ul li ul li {
    background-color:transparent/*!important*/;
    width:150px;
}
#mid-nav ul li ul li ul li a {
    background-color:transparent/*!important*/;
    font-size: 12px;

}
#mid-nav ul li ul li ul li:hover {
    background-color:#b4b4b4!important;
    color:#fff;
}
#mid-nav ul li ul li ul li:hover > a{
    background-color:#b4b4b4!important;
    color:#fff;
}
.menu-depth-1{
    background: #cfcfcf; /* Old browsers                           SHADOW AND GRADIENT */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #cfcfcf 0%, #e2e2e2 50%, #cfcfcf 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%, #cfcfcf), color-stop(50%, #e2e2e2), color-stop(100%, #cfcfcf)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #cfcfcf 0%, #e2e2e2 50%, #cfcfcf 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, #cfcfcf 0%, #e2e2e2 50%, #cfcfcf 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, #cfcfcf 0%, #e2e2e2 50%, #cfcfcf 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #cfcfcf 0%, #e2e2e2 50%, #cfcfcf 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cfcfcf', endColorstr='#cfcfcf', GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 fallback on horizontal gradient */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 8px 8px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 8px 8px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 8px 8px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

and my epic failure of an excuse jQuery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    //  $("#nav-menu-item-68").hover(function(){
    //      console.log($(this));
    //      $("#testtt").slideDown( 10000,function(){
    //      alert("The slideDown() method is finished!");   });
    //      console.log($(this).children('ul'));
    //  },function(){
    //    $(this).find('ul').slideUp( "fast" );
    //        
    //    });
    //cache nav
    var nav = $("#mid-nav");

    //add indicator and hovers to submenu parents
    nav.find("li").each(function () {
        if ($(this).find("ul").length > 0) {
            $("<span>").text("^").appendTo($(this).children(":first"));

            //show subnav on hover
            $("#nav-menu-item-68").mouseenter(function () {
                $("#testtt").stop(true, true).slideDown();
            });

            //hide submenus on exit
            $(this).mouseleave(function () {
                $("testtt").stop(true, true).slideUp();
            });
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

I am starting to think that maybe the problem lies inside of my css (as well as my JS)

Any pushes in the right direction would help (at this point my JS is useless)

Edit:

I forgot to mention all the things that I have tried and the results that they have had...

```
$(".topmenu").children('li').hover(function(){
       $(this).slideDown();
});
```

This was my first attempt and it does nothing. I have used console logging to make sure that in other attempted that I am selecting the right classes/id's

then next thing I did was similar to above but it would only slide the text and not the entire containing UL.

Have been trying to figure this out for too long now! Ahhhhh!

Thanks

C

Comment: I don't see what the problem is, it looks animated to me...

Comment: Yes, new links slide down when I hover.

Comment: Oh, never mind, I clicked a link and it went to the actual site. I guess no, not in the fiddle, sorry. I'll check it out again.

Comment: Tidy-ed up, enabled jQuery in fiddle, fixed a syntax error in the script: http://jsfiddle.net/yRNQt/3/ Still not working, but it goes crazy sliding when I hover, maybe you can work from here.

Comment: Thank you, I believe the freak out is all CSS problems! What was the fix?

Comment: There was an extra `)};` at the end of the script.

Comment: Still having problems with this!!!

Comment: [Here ya go](http://jsfiddle.net/yRNQt/19/), gotta change find `li` to find `a`.

Comment: Not to sure what that achieved?